# boost asio timer hangs the second time I read async

Tags: c++, boost, asio

I have a RS485 communication that I talk over with boost::asio::serial_port. I'm testing what happens when there is no connection. The first time the timer cancels the operation. The second time the program just hangs on io.run(). I'm confused, because I create a new fresh timer, reset io and try to have a clean plate before I start to read anything from the wire.

```cpp
boost::asio::io_context io;
boost::asio::serial_port port;

std::size_t readUntil(std::vector<char>& buffer, char delim, std::chrono::microseconds timeout) {
    using boost::system::error_code;
    error_code read_result {};
    size_t msglen = 0;
    io.reset();

    boost::asio::system_timer timer(io, timeout);
    boost::asio::async_read_until(port, boost::asio::dynamic_buffer(buffer), delim, [&](error_code ec, size_t n) {
            timer.cancel();
            read_result = ec;
            msglen = n;
        }
    );
    timer.async_wait([&](error_code ec) { 
        if (!ec) {
            port.cancel();
            throw exception::read_exception(exception::read_exception::Code::TIME_OUT);
        }
    });
    io.run(); // Hangs here, the second time, not the first

    if (read_result) {
        std::stringstream sstream;
        sstream << read_result;
        throw exception::read_exception(exception::read_exception::Code::PORT, sstream.str());
    }
    return msglen;
}

int main() {
//set up port options (baudrate etc)
for(size_t i = 0; i<10; i++) {
std::vector<char> buffer;
readUntil(buffer, '\', std::chrono::microseconds(1000));
}

}
```

Comment: So the _first time_ you get an unhandled exception right?  I mean, you never catch the exception thrown from the timer expiry.  Have you tried looking at `ec` within the timer expiry to see if it is getting called back (with `ec == true`) and therefore not canceling/closing the `port`?

Comment: That is a VERY good point